# How to get data from object in Python

Tags: python

I want to get the discord.user_id, I am VERY new to python and just need help getting this data.
I have tried everything and there is no clear answer online.
currently, this works to get a data point in the attributes section

```
pledge.relationship('patron').attribute('first_name')
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  In particular, we expect a minimal example and text we can copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json(path_to_your/file.json)
```

The ourput will be a DataFrame which is a matrix, in which the json attributes will be the names of the columns. You will have to manipulate it afterwards, which is preferable, as the operations on DataFrames are optimized in terms of processing time.

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) is the official documentation, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the whole object is call myObject, you can obtain the discord.user_id by calling myObject.json_data.attributes.social_connections.discord.user_id

Comment: Thanks for your answer however it did not work. Here is the error code 
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filename", line 45, in <module>
    print(pledge.relationship('patron').json_data.attributes.social_connections.discord.user_id)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'attribute```